# Masking to limit the values in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, masking

I want to limit the X axis depending on Y value such as `y <= 0 or y > 100` in plotting graph using the mask as below.

However, it doesn't work well as below image. Could you give me some advice about where is the problem in the code?

Actually, it doesn't matter method such as mask if I can plot just scope of x for 'y < 0'.

I have used CSV data frame value using pandas and treat missing values as the previous value using `df.ffill()`

```
        df = pd.read_csv(file.csv)
        df1 = df.ffill()

        x = np.array(df1['A'])
        y = np.array(df1['B'])
        z = np.array(df1['C'])

        x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y <= 0) | (y > 100), x)

        fig, (ax2, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2)
        ax1.set_xlabel('X Axis')
        ax1.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
        ax2.set_ylabel('Z Axis')

        ax1.set_ylim([-10, 40])
        ax2.set_ylim([-5, 5])
        ax1.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])
        ax2.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])

        ax1.plot(x, y, color='k', linewidth=1)
        ax2.plot(x, z, color='k', linewidth=1)

        plt.show()
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your plot. Could you print out `[x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()]`? In my opinion this should work.

Comment: @scleronomic  `[79.41371, 135.2098]` is value of `print([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])`. And there are error message which are  "invalid value encountered in less `x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y < 0) | (y > 100), x)`" and "invalid value encountered in greater `x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y < 0) | (y > 100), x)`"

Comment: @scleronomic `x_for_ax1` doesn't work now...

Comment: How can you print `print([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])` if `x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y < 0) | (y > 100), x)` doesn't work? Could you provide exactly the code that produced the plot, or exactly the code that produced an error, otherwise it is hard to help. Based on the error message it seems that there are still some `NaN` or `Inf` in `y`. Could you `print(np.isnan(y).any())`

Comment: @scleronomic It's the `True` when I `print(np.isnan(y).any())` and I have edited code exactly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens if you add `y = np.nan_to_num(y, nan=0)`?

Comment: @scleronomic `False` and `[ 0.    0.    0.   ... 10.29 10.29 10.29]` I think the reason is that there are null values in Y column that's why I use `df.ffill()` to treat missing values. I have attached the column capture file as above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208396/discussion-between-scleronomic-and-jane-lee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, just tried to recreate your problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(75, 145)
y = (np.sin((x/5)) + 1) * 10
y[:20] = 0
z = np.random.random(x.shape)
z[:20] = 0

x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y <= 0) | (y > 100), x)

fig, (ax2, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2)
ax1.set_ylim([-10, 40])
ax2.set_ylim([-5, 5])
ax1.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])  # Comment out 
ax2.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])  # for left image

ax1.plot(x, y, color='k', linewidth=1)
ax2.plot(x, z, color='k', linewidth=1)
```

If I run this code with some example data, I get the right figure.
In left figure I don't set the x limits:

[image: rectangles]
[image: With Limits]

Could you provide `y`, maybe there are `NaN's` in it after all?